# Is there a better way to write this code in python

Tags: python, pandas

`(df['fixed_acidity'] > 6.3).sum() - (df['fixed_acidity'] > 8).sum()`

Is there a better way to write this code in python

I would like to know the number of values in that specific column in the data frame  that have the values that are within the range of 6.3 and 8

Comment: Can you explain why the result is different? 

`print(df['fixed_acidity'].between(6.3, 8, inclusive=False).sum())`

3824 

`print((df['fixed_acidity']>6.3).sum()-(df['fixed_acidity']>8).sum())`

3946

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with `inclusive=False`:

```
df['fixed_acidity'].between(6.3, 8, inclusive=False).sum()
```

But codes working different, because `between` working exclusive for both values, so difference is if count `8` values or not:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fixed_acidity':[6.3,3,8,6.7,7.8,8]})

print ((df['fixed_acidity'] > 6.3).sum() - (df['fixed_acidity'] > 8).sum())
4
print (((df['fixed_acidity'] > 6.3) & (df['fixed_acidity'] <= 8)).sum())
4


print (df['fixed_acidity'].between(6.3, 8, inclusive=False).sum())
2
print (((df['fixed_acidity'] > 6.3) & (df['fixed_acidity'] < 8)).sum())
2
```

Comment: Can you explain why the result is different? 

`print(df['fixed_acidity'].between(6.3, 8, inclusive=False).sum())` 3824

`print((df['fixed_acidity']>6.3).sum()-(df['fixed_acidity']>8).sum())` 3946

Comment: @MysaraAltawansy - Answer was edited.